# Node axios script fails with 414 error in only one of three environments

Tags: node.js, axios

When querying an on-prem server's REST API using the same node.js script, 2 of 3 clients have a 100% success rate (Status 200).  The third client has a 100% failure rate, with `414` errors.

| Client | Status Code | OS | Node Version | Axios Version |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Client 1 | 200 | MacOS 10.15.7 | Node 14.18.1 | Axios 0.21.4 |
| Client 2 | 200 | Ubuntu 18.04.5 | Node 14.10 | Axios 0.21.1 |
| Client 3 | 414 | MacOS 11.4 | Node 14.18.1 | Axios 0.21.4 |

You can see client 1 and 3 are virtually identical, yet client 3 fails every time and client 1 succeeds every time.  Client 2 uses a different os and package versions, yet succeeds as well.

The problematic request is the third in a chain.  The first two requests succeed on all three clients.  The third request is large, a POST with a body size of 266k.

We have inspected the headers, request objects, etc and have found no discrepancies (though may have overlooked something.)  Where lies the gremlin?

Comment: Did you compare the requests themselves: headers + body?

Comment: @Anatoly regrettably yes--could not identify any difference...stumped